# Psalm 37:4 & Psalm 20:4 "...grant you your heart’s desire..." and "...give you the desires of your heart..." "dual-natured layers of meaning"

Tags: translation-philosophy, symbolism, layers-of-meaning, metaphor

> Psalm 20:1-6
>
> 1 May the Lord answer you in the day of trouble! May the name of the
> God of Jacob set you securely on high! 2 May He send you help from the
> sanctuary And support you from Zion! 3 May He remember all your meal
> offerings And find your burnt offering [a]acceptable! [b]Selah.
>
> **4 May He grant you your heart’s desire And fulfill all your [c]counsel!** 5 [d]We will sing for joy over your [e]victory, And in
> the name of our God we will set up our banners. May the Lord fulfill
> all your petitions.
>
> 6 Now I know that the Lord saves His anointed; He will answer him from
> His holy heaven With the [f]saving strength of His right hand.

> Psalm 37:1-6
>
> 1 Do not fret because of evildoers, Be not envious toward wrongdoers.
> 2 For they will wither quickly like the grass And fade like the green
> herb. 3 Trust in the Lord and do good; Dwell in the land and
> [a]cultivate faithfulness.
>
> **4 Delight yourself in the Lord; And He will give you the desires of your heart.** 5 Commit your way to the Lord, Trust also in Him, and He
> will do it. 6 He will bring forth your righteousness as the light And
> your judgment as the noonday.

The phrases in Psalm 37:4 and Psalm 20:4 that state:

"...grant you your heart’s desire..."
and
"...give you the desires of your heart..."

can be viewed in 2 ways(dual-natured layers of meaning):

A) the more obvious view of God actually granting us what we personally desire in our hearts

B) , and the more subtle/nuanced view of God creating/inventing desires in our hearts(i.e., He as The Divine God Himself placing desires that God Himself created/invented in our hearts).

1. Is there some kind of

a) Theological terminology/term for the dual-natured layers of meaning that can be associated with  said verses?

and/or

b) English literary device for the dual-natured layers of meaning that can be associated with said verses?

2. Could someone also please post back other scripture verses or passages in the Bible that have this similar dual-natured layers of meaning?

Comment: See my answer here >>  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60462/does-living-by-the-law-of-the-spirit-mean-living-by-the-law/60471#60471

Answer (score 1):

Is there some kind of Theological terminology/term for the dual-natured layers of meaning that can be associated with  said verses?

I often read the Bible according to the Co-Reality model: horizontal and verticle perspectives, and importantly both views are true. This practice is consistent with the OP's dual-natured layers of meaning. So yes, Co-Reality Model is a theological term for this but there are probably other terms as well.

Horizontally, the stress is on "we":
A) the more obvious view of God actually granting us what **we** personally desire in our hearts

Vertically, the stress is on "God":
B) and the more subtle/nuanced view of God creating/inventing desires in our hearts(i.e., He as The Divine God Himself placing desires that God Himself created/invented in our hearts).

Both A and B are true.

Could someone also please post back other scripture verses or passages in the Bible that have this similar dual-natured layers of meaning?

Vertically, God's hardening of Pharaoh's heart in
Exodus 9:12

> But the LORD hardened Pharaoh’s heart and he would not listen to Moses and Aaron, just as the LORD had said to Moses.

Horizontally, Pharaoh hardened his own heart in
Exodus 8:15

> But when Pharaoh saw that there was relief, he hardened his heart and would not listen to Moses and Aaron, just as the LORD had said.

More detail is in my answer to [Free Will in the Old Testament](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48946/free-will-in-the-old-testament/)

Comment: Is this a comment or a question?  Either way it does not appear to be an answer.

Comment: I added more :)